# How to solve $E[(W_tW_t+s)^2] $

Tags: expectation, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation

$E[(W_tW_t+s)^2] $ this is the expectation I want to solve. Is this the correct way? $W_t$ is Brownian Motion. The time line is $t<t+s$

$E[(W_tW_t+s)^2] = E[W_t^2 (W_t+s)^2] = E[E[W_t^2 (W_t+s)^2 | W_t]] 
= E[W_t^2E[  (W_t+s)^2 | W_t]] =E[W_t^2E[  (W_s)^2]] =  sE[W_t^2] = st                                                       $

I am trying to solve this by conditioning on $W_t$ and Iterated Expectations. Is this the right way or I am missing something obvious?

Comment: Please start writing `W_{t+s}`  instead of `W_t+s` to get $$W_{t+s}$$ Re your question, no conditioning is needed since $W_{t+s}=W_t+Z$ where $Z$ is centered normal with variance $s$ and independent of $W_t$ hence $$E((W_tW_{t+s})^2)=E(W_t^4)+2E(W_t^3)E(Z)+E(W_t^2)E(Z^2)=3t^2+0+ts$$

Comment: @Did - Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Got it was doing a stupid mistake
$E[(W_tW_t+s)^2] = E[W_t^2 (W_t+s)^2] = E[E[W_t^2 (W_t+s)^2 | W_t]] 
= E[W_t^2E[  (W_t+s)^2 | W_t]]
$

$
E[  (W_t+s)^2 | W_t]] = E[(W_t+s -W_t + W_t)^2|W_t] = E[(W_t+s - W_t)^2+ W_t^2 + 2W_t(W_t+s-W_t)|W_t] = E[(W_t+s - W_t)^2|W_t] + E[W_t^2|W_t]+ 2E[W_t(W_t+s-W_t)|W_t] = s+W_t^2 + 2W_tE[(W_t+s-W_t|W_t] = S+ W_t^2 + 0 = s+W_t^2
$

$
E[W_t^2E[  (W_t+s)^2 | W_t]] = E[W_t^2(s+W_t^2)]= sE[W_t^2] + E[W_t^4]=st+ 3t^2
$

And that should be the answer